# Can anybody tell me more about Gandabherunda?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, avatars, narasimha

Gandabherunda was a form of Narasimha. I want to learn more about him, can't find any info on the internet apart from Wikipedia.

Comment: It is a part of local folklores and sthala purana text. Similar to Just like the story of Lord Shiv ji saving sage Markandeya by killing lord Yamraj is not found in any prominent text.

Comment: The Wikipedia article is actually about a different Gandabherunda!

Comment: Gandabherunda was likely propped up by somebody like Vijayīndra Tirtha in a text like Śaivasarvasvakhaṇdana (a viciously polemical work which portrays Bhagavāna Śiva as a sort of 'false god'). Vijayīndra Tirtha is renowned for works like Appayakapolacapeṭika/How to hit on the forehead of Appaya (where he launched personal attacks against the Śaiva Advaita scholar Appaya Dīkṣita for attacking Madhva in his Madhvatantramukhamardana/How to rub the face of Madhva's system against ground) & Turiyaśivakhaṇdana (where he refutes the existence of a Triguṇātīta Śiva separate from Tāmasī Kālagnirudra).

Answer (score 1):

Since Gandabherunda is a folkloric form, there is likely no scriptural mention of him. So, we can turn to scholarly works, which explain that there are in fact two Gandabherundas- one that's a bird that interacts with Narasimha and one that's a form of Narasimha himself, just with eight heads. I assume you're talking about the second one, so:

> There is a curious representation of Narasimha (an avatar of Vishnu) who is called  Gandabherunda- Narasimha with eight heads. The eight heads are those of **Gandabherunda**, **lion** (simha), **tiger** (vyaghra), **horse** (asva), **boar** (kroda), **monkey** (sakha-mrga), **eagle** (khaga-tat), and **bear** (bhalluka).
>
> [(Encyclopaedia of Indian Iconography)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Encyclopaedia_of_Indian_Iconography/zhQnAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)

This form is also known as *Ashtamukha Narasimha.*